# Visualize robot in gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have gmapping working for my mobile robot.
[image: image description]

Now I can see the position of my robot by visualizing tf, so that I can see the base link and laser.
But I want to see a simplified version of my robot, a rectangle should do, but how do I get this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is my current launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

<!-- start hokuyo_node -->
<node name="hokuyo_node" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" output="screen"/>

  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_footprint"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="nav"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>


<!-- start odometry_node -->
<node name="odometry" pkg="mastering_ros_demo_pkg" type="odometry" output="screen"/> 


<!-- start g_mapping -->
<node name="slam_gmapping" pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="ogain" value="10"/>        <!-- default 3 -->
    <param name="throttle_scans" value="1"/> 
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="1"/>    
    <param name="iterations" value="20"/>       <!-- default 5 -->
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>    <!-- default 0.075 -->
    <param name="delta" value="0.03"/>      <!-- default 0.05 -->
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.5"/>    <!-- default 1.0 -->
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5"/>   <!-- default 0.5 -->
</node>


    <!-- Frame names -->
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<!--    
<param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />
-->
    
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_frame" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="base_frame" />
   
    <!-- Tf use -->   
    <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
<!--
 <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
-->
     <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
    <!-- Map size / start point -->
    <param name="map_resolution" value="0.010"/>
    <param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
    <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
    <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
    
    <!-- Map update parameters -->
    <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
    <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
    <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
    <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
    
    <!-- Advertising config --> 
    <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
    
    <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
    <param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    
    <!-- Debug parameters -->
    <!--
      <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
      <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
      <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
    -->
    <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
  <!--
</node>
-->    
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_nav_broadcaster" args="-0.45 0 0 3.1765 0 3.1415 /base_link /laser 100"/>



 <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234170/visualize-robot-in-gmapping/) by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you add the [robot model](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/RobotModel) to the topics you are visualizing in RViz, you'll be able to see whatever model is represented by the parameter "robot_description". This is your URDF file.

If you are using a pre-built robot (i.e. turtlebot) this is usually set for you.

If you are using a custom robot, you'll need to set it yourself in your launch file. Here is an example:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find pkg_name)/urdf/robot_urdf.xacro'" />
```

If you are not running xacro, the command is similar:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find pkg_name)/urdf/robot_urdf.urdf" />
```

Since you are able to see the robot tf frames, I assume you're running [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) and [robot_joint_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher). Both of these use the robot_description parameter, so it is likely to already be set.

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on 2016-05-12**:
Do I need the xacro file? Or can I just work with my urdf file?

**Comment by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) on 2016-05-12**:
You do not need the xacro file. [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) is just really useful for URDF files, it allows you to parameterize them. I'll change my answer accordingly.